# When space bar is hit log the time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to log the time in HH:MM:SS when the space bar is hit. I have found in my research its easier to use cocoa then foundation because cocoa has a NSEvent class that can sense key strokes. There was a similar question asked about how to sense double space bars hit but it did not satisfy how to relate that back to my program.

Code Below:

```
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date ];
NSTimeInterval elaspedTime = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];

-(void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *) theEvent{
    NSString* spaceBarPressed = [ theEvent characters ];
    if( [spaceBarPressed isEqualToString:@"" ] ){
        if(theEvent.type == NSKeyDown )
            NSLog(@"Space bar hit" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your question - what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 7):

It can be done like this:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent { 

    if ([theEvent keyCode] == 49) { //Spacebar keyCode is 49
        NSLog(@"Time is: %@", [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]);
    }
}
```